# Portal Sharing Content to Individual User

Tags: arcgis-portal, contents-pane

Can you only share content on portal to groups within an organization or is it possible to share to individual users within that organization? I remember being able to share to a specific user in my graduate course last year, but my company's portal doesn't allow individual sharing. Not sure if this is an administrative setting or if this functionality no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if we ever had such an option for sharing items.

If you want to share an item with an individual you would still have to create a group and add that member in the group.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything about sharing content with other members. However, if a member is in the same organization, you can transfer content from one user to another or change ownership of said content.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/manage-items.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F9D72CA4252E4EB18F4B081C27ADF527